# How do you force focus on an HTML input element?

Tags: clojurescript

In jQuery you can force focus onto an input using something along the lines:

```
$("input[name='text']").focus();
```

But how is it done in ClojureScript (preferable something Enfocus friendly) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have been very tired, the following works :)

```
(ef/at "input[name='text']" (focus))
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using enfocus, you can do this by calling javascript functions, e.g.

```
(-> js/document (.querySelector "input[name='text']") (.focus))
```

or using .. threading:

```
(.. js/document (querySelector "input[name='text']") (focus))
```